# ASP.NET WebForm DataBoundControl controls: Rendering Formatted Fonts

Tags: asp.net

```
<%#:string.Format("Home Phone: {0}",Item.Person.HomePhone)%>
```

In the previous binding definition for ASP.NET Webform DataBoundControl controls type, how can i render the phone number with formated font? 
For example bold:

Home Phone: **123456**

An important detail es that "Home Phone:" is not formatted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is whatever inside `<%# %>` will end up with html encoded.

You might want to try moving the html tag outside of binding.

```
Home Phone: <strong><%# Item.Person.HomePhone %></strong>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<%#:string.Format("Home Phone: <b>{0}</b>",Item.Person.HomePhone)%>
```

Comment: Not working, rendering this instead:

Home Phone:<b>123456</b>

Comment: Strange, works here. Can u post how original line is rendered in browser as HTML?

Comment: Sure, here it is, it is rendering the named character entity reference.
Home Phone: &lt;b&gt;123456&lt;/b&gt;